# Android application stops unexpectedly when running

Tags: java, android

when testing my application in the emulator(I'm using Eclipse) it shows me "The application Counter(com.ian.counter) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." when running it. I've searched and searched for an answer but I've found none. Anyone know the problem?

Code:

```
package com.ian.counter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CounterActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    int count = 0;
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void Count(){
        count ++;
        textView1.setText(Integer.toString(count));
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
12-28 16:59:20.615: D/AndroidRuntime(353): Shutting down VM
12-28 16:59:20.686: W/dalvikvm(353): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ian.counter/com.ian.counter.CounterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at com.ian.counter.CounterActivity.<init>(CounterActivity.java:10)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
12-28 16:59:20.756: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set the `textView1` variable before the layout has been set. You need to define it as a variable and then assign it in `onCreate()` after you've called `setContentView()`. Like this:

```
package com.ian.counter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CounterActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView textView1;
    int count = 0;
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textView1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    public void Count(){
        count ++;
        textView1.setText(Integer.toString(count));
    }
}
```

Just copy and paste the above, that'll work just fine.

Comment: Thanks so much! Runs fine now.

Comment: Cheers! Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way. I should probably tell you that you're supposed to mark answers as accepted if they're useful. Keep it in mind in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

You should put this line

`textView1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);`

after

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

and you just declare TextView in the begining

```
TextView textView1;
```

dont try to use `findViewById(R.id.textView1);` while declaraing instance variable as view does not exist at that point of time.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code should look like:

```
TextView textView1 = null; 
    int count = 0;
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
     TextView textView1 =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    public void Count(){
        count ++;
        textView1.setText(Integer.toString(count));
    }
```